# When does $\text{Set}^{C^{\text{op}}}$ have split regular epi?

Tags: ct.category-theory

> Is it possible to understand when in a presheaf category $\text{Set}^{C^{\text{op}}}$ every regular epimorphism splits?

Obviously I am looking for conditions on $C$ such that this is the case.

Since the Yoneda embedding does not preserve colimits one can't even infer that $C$ must have split regular epis.

Please, assume choice, which means that $\text{Set} \cong \text{Set}^{1}$ has split regular epi.

Comment: Are regular epis the same as pointwise epis?

Comment: Greg, it says in n-Lab that a morphism $Y\to X$ is called a regular epi iff it is the coequalizer of some pair of maps into $Y$.

Comment: Yes. I still wonder if it is the same. Given an epimorphism $f\colon Y\twoheadrightarrow X$, one can form the pullback $Z=Y\times_X Y$ if it exists. There are two morphisms $Z\Rightarrow Y$, and in good situations $f$ is the coequalizer of these two morphisms. You can use this construction to prove that every epimorphism is regular in the category of sets, and it seemed to me that it also works in the category of functors to sets. I was wondering if I was missing something.

Comment: @GregoryArone As Harry says, it's true that in a topos, every epimorphism is regular, and as you say, it's by the same argument as in $Set$. The fact every epimorphism is a levelwise epimorphism is more special -- it really requires you to be in a presheaf category. The proof that comes to mind is to explicitly construct image factorizations by taking the levelwise image of a natural transformation and showing that it is a presheaf. Putting these together, regular epis in a presheaf category are the same as levelwise epis.

Comment: @TimCampion Another way to show that epis in a presheaf category are levelwise is to use that a map is epi iff its cokernel pair is an isomorphism, and use the facts that colimits and isomorphisms are levelwise.

Answer (score 6):

You can replace 'regular epimorphism' with just 'epimorphism'. Presheaf categories are all Grothendieck topoi.  The nLab says that a Grothendieck topos has the property that all epis split if and only if it is equivalent to the category of sheaves on a complete Boolean algebra.  So a sufficient condition follows from this: It holds in the case where C is the site associated with a complete Boolean algebra.

See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+choice

The reason why it isn't necessary and sufficient is that the category of presheaves on a site can be the category of sheaves on a different site.

Comment: A similar argument shows that $C$ must be a groupoid. In fact $\text{Set}^{C^{\text{op}}}$ must be boolean, as you proved, and when a presheaf topos it boolean $C$ must be a groupoid.

Comment: If $C$ must be a groupoid, then I think the answer to the question is "if and only if $C$ is equivalent to a discrete category". To begin with, it is enough to consider the case when $C$ is a groupoid with a single object, i.e. a group. For a non-trivial group, there is always an epimorphism between $G$ sets that is not split. For example, the map from a free $G$-orbit to a trivial $G$-orbit.

Comment: I don't see how to go from groupoid to group.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti It is enough to consider connected categories, and every connected groupoid is equivalent to a group. Alternatively, you can restate the argument for groupoids: Suppose $C$ is a groupoid, and $x$ is an object of $C$ with a non-trivial automorphism. Let $F(-)=\hom_C(x, -)$ be the functor represented by $x$ and let $*$ be the constant one-point functor. It is easy to check that the epimorphism $F\to *$ is not split.

Comment: Ooops, I wrote a covariant representable functor instead of a contravariant one, but it does not really make a difference.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: it might be worthwhile writing up your observation as an answer. And it sounds like a characterization to me.